# How to get docker registry working on windows server 2016

Tags: docker, docker-registry, windows-server-2016

I have windows server 2016 version 1607.
It is running Docker EE version 17.06.2-ee-3 (both client and server)

I want to get a registry running so I ran

`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2`

It responds:

`Unable to find image 'registry:2' locally
2: Pulling from library/registry
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries`

This worked fine on my Windows 10 machine. Is there something special with Server 2016?

I found this [entry](https://forums.docker.com/t/installing-a-private-registry-on-windows-server-2016/22279/4) but it's almost a year old. Is this still the only way to do it?

Also, I found the [Docker Trusted Registry](https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/dtr/2.1/guides/). Is that something that should be considered for windows server 2016 as an alternative?

Comment: I get the same response also on Windows 10.

Comment: I think the command that you mentioned is working for Linux Container. So probably the reason that it works on your Windows 10 is that you used Linux container.

Answer (score 0):

Running a Registry Container
The basic usage will run a registry, store the data in the container, and publish port 5000:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 sixeyed/registry
```

You'll want to host-mount the c:\data directory, where the image is configured to store registry data. If you're using the registry from a single host, you can also use a fixed IP address for the container:

```
mkdir c:\registry-data

docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --ip 172.24.202.164 -v c:\registry-data:c:\data sixeyed/registry
```

reference
https://hub.docker.com/r/sixeyed/registry/